# iPhone SDK and Multipage tiff

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to access the iphone APIs to read a multipage TIFF image file format, dose anyone know how:, if not how can I build and use the open source libtiff on iphone/xcode.

Answer (score 6):

I've created my own solution for this: [NSTiffSplitter](https://github.com/Sharrp/NSTiffSplitter).
You can find it on [github](https://github.com/Sharrp/NSTiffSplitter).

```
NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"tiff"];
NSTiffSplitter* splitter = [[NSTiffSplitter alloc] initWithPathToImage:pathToImage];
UIImage *page = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[splitter dataForImage:page]];
yourImageView.image = page;
[page release];
```

Comment: Thanks! Very appreciated! :-)

Comment: @5hrp NSTiffSplitter helps in reading a multipage tiff. Can we create multi-page tiff in iOS. can you suggest any lib.

Comment: Sorry @iOSDev didn't touch this subject for years, so I don't know the answer for your question. But if you really need this it shouldn't be hard to write it by your own. NSTiffSplitter took only one day with careful specs reading.