# Assets don't load on iOS8 but they do in iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently working on an app where i need to support iOS8 and iOS9.
The app is being developed with Swift 2 with Xcode 7.2.1.

When i run the app on iOS9 everything is working perfectly and smoothly, on a simulator or on a device.

But when i run it on iOS8 (Sim or Device) any of my assets is loading and i got this error in the console.

```
-[CUIThemeRendition newImageFromCSIDataSlice:ofBitmap: usingColorspace:] Unsupported pixel format in CSI got 4
Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data
```

All my assets are located in a AssetCatalog and they are all .png

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911627/image-resources-xcassets-not-displayed-correctly-on-yosemite-in-application-bu, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643904/xcode-6-beta-3-unsupported-pixel-format-in-csi-or-unable-to-create-unsliced-i. Possible reason XCode bug, possible workaround not to use asset catalog

Comment: Hello Luis. Please don't include the answer in the question. Ever. :) Questions should remain questions. You can post your answer yourself *as an answer to your question*, it's perfectly ok to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to that problem. Basically it's because you got in the Asset Catalog Compiler options the Optimization field set to the property save, set it to nil and it works !

Answer (score 0):

See these questions:

[Image resources for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244494/image-resources-for-ios)

[Why does resource bundle copy .png as .tiff images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560799/why-does-resource-bundle-copy-png-as-tiff-images)

The short answer that worked for me is:
In your bundle target Go to,

Buld Settings > COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES and set to NO